Почему движимый и (он) движется имеют разные начальные формы?
Движимый: начальной формой этого глагола является устаревшее слово «движити». Почему у слова «движется» другая начальная форма?


Слово «движимый» может быть либо причастием (движимый силой ветра), либо прилагательным (недвижимое имущество), но быть глаголом ему не дано.
Согласно https://pishugramotno.ru/morfologiya/%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9 начальной формой причастия «движимый» является глагол «двигать», а начальной формой прилагательного  «движимый» - прил. «движимый».
Для возвратного глагола «движется» начальной формой считают инфинитив «двигаться».
https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/glagol/nachalnaya-forma-spuskalas-spuskayutsya.html
На вопрос «почему?» приходится отвечать: «таковы существующие Правила».

Если под «разными начальными формами» подразумевались корни с чередованием согласных г/ж/з, то разобраться в вопросе поможет статья «движить» (в викисловаре):



устар. то же, что двигать ◆ Длиннокрылые ласточки и стрижи быстро разрезают воздух; плавно, почти неприметно движат крыльями коршун и сокол в верхних слоях воздуха. К. Ф. Рулье, «Общая зоология», 1850 г. (цитата из НКРЯ)
от праслав. *dvigati «поднимать, двигать вверх», от кот. в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав. двигнѫ, двигнѫти, движѫ, двиѕати, русск. двигать, укр. дви́гати, болг. ди́гам, сербохорв. ди̏гнути, ди̏ħи, словенск. dvígati, dvîgam, чешск. zdvihnout, польск. dźwigąć «поднять, возвести», в.-луж. zběhać, н.-луж. zwigaś. Дальнейшее родство неясно. Возможно сопоставление с англос. twiccian «рвать, дёргать», англ. twitch. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

Как видим, М.Фасмер считал, что форма «dvigati» дала начало родственным формам «движу» и «двизати».
Реже всего в современном языке встречается форма «двизати»:
Сашка подвизался сначала курьером, потом устроился в фирму — замороженными продуктами торговал. [Маша Трауб. Нам выходить на следующей (2011)]
В отличие от «двиз», форма «движ» весьма продуктивна, например: подвижный ребенок, движимое и недвижимое имущество, подвижка тектонических плит...
Но нужно знать, какие мотивы движут людьми, нужно понимать, что не все примитивно. [Юлия Кантор. Сергей Безруков: «На телевидении я делаю то, что хочу» // «Известия», 2001.09.24]
Движущий фактор эволюции в экономических системах. Словарь терминов [Владимир Горбачев. Концепции современного естествознания (2003)]
Встречаются (в НКРЯ) и примеры новых образований:
Он хотел еще спросить, а какую, собственно, цель преследует вся эта «движуха», но побоялся, что такой вопрос может обидеть ее. [А. А. Уткин. Дорога в снегопад (2008-2010)]
Время прошло, тот движ заглох, но «Zdob» нашли в себе силы сменить тему и выдать нечто новое — тоже «молдовенеск», но уже далеко не «хардкоре». [«Здоб ши Здуб» отвечают на зуб, а точнее - на наши вопросы (2004) // «Хулиган», 15.07.2004]

А вы не могли бы дать короткий ответ на вопрос "почему" в начале вашего ответа. А то я так и не поняла причину. И автору вопроса будет это легче понять.  Почему мы не стали писать "движемый", форму "двигаемый" тоже не используем, а обратились к форме устаревшего глагола "движимый".

Откуда такое неприятие суффикса «им», если: причастия настоящего времени образуются от основы глаголов настоящего времени с помощью суффиксов -ущ-, -ющ-, -ащ-, -ящ-, -ом-, -ем-, -им

Через некоторое время из кухни донесся ее тихий, полный боли и обиды, гасимый в подушку плач. [Анатолий Ференчук. Пути-дороги // «Огонек». № 27, 1959]

Вред, изредка творимый обществу, классу, расе, государству бессмысленной добротой, меркнет в свете, который исходит от людей, наделенных ею. [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, часть 2 (1960)]

Мягкие движения сливаются в гулкий рокот, разносимый по бескрайнему городу. [Александр Волков. Алло, Ариадна! // «Знание ― сила», 2003]

"Начальная форма причастия - именительный падеж единственного числа мужского рода. Все глагольные признаки причастия соотносятся с начальной формой глагола - неопределенной формой". Если Вы считаете, что это правило следует объяснить - не буду Вам мешать...

Я могу сказать короче: для неусекаемых основ (суффикс А сохраняется) возможно только 1-е спряжение. Слышали об этом? Остается 2-й вопрос: почему "двигаемый" не используется?  А правил мне не надо, достаточно грамматики.

Нашла для вас глагол, который любит суффикс ЕМ: колебаться – колеблемый, также принять - приемлемый. Как только Л появляется, сразу и любовь у них.  А вот шипящие действительно любят только суффикс ИМ.  Фонетика всем правит, а не начальные формы.

Пусть буду я огнем калИМ - останусь непоколебИМ.

Сами сочиняли? Класс! Люблю поэтов, они все мои друзья)  // А здесь все в норме.  Глаголы с усекаемой формой могут относиться к обоим спряжениям.  Появилось Л – суффикс ЕМ, нет Л  – суффикс ИМ.  Напишите об этом правило)

Неужели мы всё стерпим, всё, растлимся без остатка.
[Л. В. Шапорина. Дневник. Том 1 (1898-1945)]

Сказки взрослым гораздо нужней.  Век двадцатый, войною палимый.  Смерть прикинется теплым дождем.
[А. М. Городницкий. Тайны и мифы науки. В поисках истины (2014)]

Спасибо. Я, как прилежный школьник, посмотрела ваши ссылки, послушала Городницкого. О сказках для взрослых.  Помнится, еще в школе по заданию учителя физики, написала рассказик "Король Вектус XIII" о скалярных и векторных величинах . Уже позже опубликовала его на Прозе.ру.  И вот года два назад его вдруг стали активно читать. Но я  убрала его, когда ученическая сказка вдруг стала нужна взрослым. Век двадцать первый превзошел двадцатый...

ВОПРОС:  Почему движимый и (он) движется имеют
разные начальные формы?
ОТВЕТ:
В современном русском языке есть глагол двигаться, имеющий две разные личные формы и разные основы: он движется и он двигается, но только одну форму движимый (нет парной формы двигаемый). Форма движимый восходит к устаревшему глаголу движити.
ПОЧЕМУ? Это ст-слав. по происхождению форма глагола, соответствующая КНИЖНОМУ характеру слова  и имеющая более  удобную фонетику. Можно также отметить СЕМАНТИЧЕСКИЙ фактор:  движимый (чем?) любопытством, инстинктом и т.д. Это внутренний фактор в отличие чисто пассивной конструкции двигаемый.
ПОДРОБНОЕ ПОЯСНЕНИЕ (всё остальное)
Примечание
 Раньше на форуме давали короткие ответы, понятные 
 по сути. Сейчас  мы пишем научные трактаты, 
 которые далеки от информационного стиля, где 
 действует правило: сначала короткий и ясный 
 ответ, а потом все остальное. А иначе ответ 
 бывает трудно найти.


Значение и грамматические формы глагола двигать(ся) указаны в Большом толковом словаре.

Глагол многозначный, всего 5 значений. Глагол интересен тем, что он является  избыточным, или изобилующим, так как имеет параллельные личные и глагольные формы, например: движется и двигается, движущийся и двигающийся. Но вот форма страд. прич. настоящего времени только одна: движимый, а формы двигаемый нет.


Справочник Как правильно: поезд двигается или движется?

Раньше глагол имел разные формы инфинитива двигать, движити и двизати, что видно из Словаря русского языка XVIII века:
ДВИ́ГАТЬ (-ти), аю, ает и дви́жу, дви́жет, ◨ (слав.) ДВИ́ЖИТИ 
(-ть), жу, жет и ДВИ́ЗА́ТИ, аю, ает и а́ю, а́ет, несов., 
ДВИ́НУТЬ и (слав.) ДВИ́ГНУТИ (-ть), ну, нет, сов., однокр.; 
Дви́гающий, Дви́жущий (-жащий), Дви́гаемый, Дви́жимый (- 
жемый), Дви́нутый, Дви́гнутый, Дви́жен, прич., Дви́гая, 
Дви́жа, деепр. кого-что.



Также: Происхождение слова двигать
И вот форма движимый соответствует глаголу движити с пометкой ст.-слав.,  который изменялся по образцу 2-го склонения.

Но почему используется только форма движимый, а не двигаемый?  Можно предположить, что эта причастная форма имеет книжный характер, как и глагол движити, что видно из примеров в Карте слов. А вот форма двигаемый не закрепилась в языке:

Поэтому в философах я видел лишь людей, движимых любопытством, а не глашатаев истины. Свита волшебника, движимая жаждой мести, ринулась в бой, но герои легко отбили нападение.Я обернулся, движимый какой-то неведомой силой, но это была лишь игра воображения.
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Большой толковый словарь русского языка
ДВИГАТЬ, -аю, -аешь и движу, движешь; двигающий и движущий; движимый; -жим, -а, -о; нсв. 1. страд. прич. прош. нет; кого-что. Перемещать, толкая или таща. Д. мебель. // Управлять перемещением, продвижением кого-, чего-л., направлять куда-л. Д. батальон в атаку. 2. страд. прич. прош. нет. (чем). Делать движения, шевелить частями тела. Д. руками. // Производить движение, перемещая что-л. Д. стулом. 3. Приводить в движение, заставлять действовать. Пар движет (двигает) колёса. // (кем-чем). Побуждать, руководить, быть причиной чьих-л. поступков. Им движет алчность. 4. что. Содействовать развитию чего-л., развивать что-л. Д. науку. 5. страд. прич. прош. нет. Разг.-сниж. Двигаться (2 зн.). Горы (горами) двигать (см. Гора). Еле (или с трудом и т.п.) двигать ногами. С трудом, медленно ходить, идти. Двигаться, -ается и -жется; страд. (1, 3-4 зн.). Двинуть (см.).
